# How to manage memcached servers in php

Tags: php, memcached

Whats the best way to manage memcache servers in php? Im especially concerned about adding/removing servers, or having 1 fail.

As far as I understand, if you simply comment out addServer() of the server you want to take out, it will screw up the entire cache pool. Is that right?

Currently I'm resorting to this:

Enabled:

```
$memcache_obj->addServer('ip', port, true, 1, 1, 15, true);
```

Disabled

```
$memcache_obj->addServer('ip', port, true, 1, 1, -1, false);
```

Is this a good idea?

What about storing the memcache server list. I have several servers which all need to connect to the memcache pool. Doing any changes requires me to edit the config on all of these servers.

What about storing the server list in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways (as far as I know) of doing it using php's Memcache library :

- the method you used, which will enable transparent failover if `memcache.allow_failover` is enabled. While doing this, the keys you set when the server is disabled will need to be recreated when the server is put back into production.
- change `memcache.hash_strategy` to consistent. This will make the hash strategy less influenced by the server pool.

Either way, disabling or removing a server from the pool will have an impact and some keys will be lost in the process.

More options are found in php's [Memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) (notice the d) library (but of course that will mean changes in the code).

Take a look at your `php.ini` and the [Memcache runtime configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php) for your current setup.

As a side-note, storing the server list in mysql is a bad idea. Best way to have it hard-coded. Would be inefficient to do a database connection and query only to get a list of servers which will give you connectivity to your fast storage buffer. Caching should be a way to avoid connecting and querying the database.